# Игра в слова в телеграмм боте на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Я пишу бота, Использую `pyTelegramBotAPI`. Написал для него функцию игры в города.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    keyboard = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    keyboard_cities = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='"Игра в города"', callback_data='cities')
    keyboard.add(keyboard_cities)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет', reply_markup=keyboard)
# клавиатура


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
    def callback_worker(call):
         if call.data == 'cities':
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Напишите город')
            user_city = call.text # пользователь начинает первый и вводит город
            if user_city.lower() == 'стоп': 
                bot.send_message((call.message.chat.id, 'Вы выиграли')) # остановка игры 
            else:
                for i in allcities:
                    if i[0].lower() == user_city[-1].lower(): 
                         b.append(i) # перебираем все города в списке, если первая буква города из списка равна последней букве введеного пользователем города мы добавляем этот город в список
                    elif user_city[-1].lower() == 'ь' or user_city[-1].lower() == 'ъ' or user_city[-1].lower() == 'й' or user_city[-1].lower() == 'ы': 
                         if i[0].lower() == user_city[-2].lower(): 
                            b.append(i) # если город заканчивается на ь,й,ъ,ы сравниваем первую букву с предпоследней
            gorod = random.choice(b) # из полученного списка выбираем рандомом одно подходящее слово
            bot.send_message((call.message.chat.id, gorod))
            b.clear() # очищаем список
```

`allcities` это список городов которые я спарсил с википедии в другом файле и просто импортировал его в файл с ботом. Главная проблема заключается в том, что мне нужно как то к переменной присвоить то что написал пользователь(переменная `user_city`).
Я проверял в отдельном файле где `user_city = input()`, все работало.
Не знаю как сделать так чтобы я мог играть с ботом.
Сама кнопка тоже работает. Если ее нажать бот попросит написать город и вот тогда происходит ошибка. Я еще не очень много знаю о правильном написании телеграмм ботов так что буду благодарен советам по оптимизации кода.

Answer (score 1):

Как по мне, проще всего сделать так:

```
def fo(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "send message")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, fo2)


def fo2(message):
    global mess
    mess = message.text #  теперь в данной переменной находится текст, который написал пользователь
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin учту)

Comment: я в итоге сделал просто с помощью команды и не использовал `bot.register_next_step_handler`